# How many installations of macports do I need

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard, 32bit-64bit, macports

Over the past couple of months I've set about using Wing IDE to do the vast majority of my programming. I chose Wing primarily because it works well with wxPython, allowing me to debug much more quickly than was the case when I was using TextWrangler alongside Terminal. A quirk of Wing however is that there is no satisfactory way to force universal builds of python to run in 32-bit mode. Since I'm using wxPython 2.8.x (32-bit only) I'm using a 32-bit-only version of python as the executable (2.7.1). So long as I'm only using the python standard library and wxPython I have no problems, my trouble begins when I start trying to install third-party modules to work with this 32-bit version of Python. I want to do all my installing using macports, but it appears that the macports I have downloaded installs modules for use only with a different version of python that happens to be universal. Essentially then this is a question about macports, and I'd appreciate clarification on the following two points:

1. If I want three versions of python on my computer (say 2.6, 2.7 and 3.2), and want to use macports to install modules for each of them, do I need three separate versions of macports - one for each python?
2. If I'm right about (1) how do I set about installing separate versions? I've looked on the macports website but can find no reference to alternative versions based on which version of python you want to use it with

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Python installed at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7` almost certainly has nothing to do with MacPorts.  You probably installed it from a `python.org` installer.  If you want to install packages to it, you should install separate versions of `easy_install` using [the Distribute package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) and/or [`pip`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) for it and directly install packages for that Python instance with them.  Those versions will be installed in the framework bin directory, `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin.` You can't manage Python packages for it from MacPorts;  that works only for MacPorts Pythons, i.e. at `/opt/local/bin`.

So it appears you have three versions of Python 2.7 installed.  The Apple-supplied system Python at `/usr/bin/python2.7`, a MacPorts-installed version at `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`, and a third (possibly from python.org) at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7` (for which there is likely a symlink at `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`).  There's nothing inherently wrong about having all three installed and the three can easily co-exist.  Just keep in mind which one you are using, either by managing your shell path or using an absolute path to each, and that any additional packages installed need to be installed to the correct Python's site-packages directory.  If you use `easy_install` or `pip`, you need to install and/or use the correct one for each.

If your goal is just to use `wx-python` with Python 2.7, there is an outstanding MacPorts issue about building a 32-bit-only version of `wx-python` because of its dependency on deprecated OS X Carbon APIs.  There appears to be [a new MacPorts port](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/python/py27-wxpython-devel/Portfile) of a Cocoa version of wxWidgets which should work in 64-bit mode.  You might want to experiment with it:

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port install py27-wxpython-devel
```

Comment: Okay, to clarify: having inspected /opt/local/bin it looks like macports has installed three versions of python: 2.4, 2.6, 2.7. The one I'm interested in is 2.7, which is a universal build. This is unfortunate because of the issue mentioned in my original post. It looks like I can do one of two things then: either forget macports and do as you suggest Ned, or somehow install a macports version of python2.7 32-bit only, thus giving me 4 macports pythons. Is this latter option even possible?

Comment: It should be possible to build a 32-bit only MacPorts python2.7 but it does take a little effort.  You'll need to ensure that MacPorts has installed 64-/32-bit universal versions of all dependent packages.  It would be better if the `py27-wxpython-devel` port works as that is clearly needed for `wx` to have a future on OS X.  Let me know if that works or not and, if not, we can try to build the 32-bit-only versions for MacPorts (I don't have time to do that right now). Also, if you *are* using a 32-bit-only 2.7 from python.org, that will have other problems on Lion (with Xcode 4).

Comment: Trying to go down the -devel root, but have already hit a problem: 'Can't install wxWidgets-devel because conflicting ports are installed: wxWidgets'. Have posted separate question about this.

Answer (score 3):

No you don't need separate versions of macport, what you need is separate versions of python.

Clear steps to do it :

1. Install macports. You should be able to use `port` command after that. You should have `/opt/local/bin` first in your path automatically, if you are using the installer for Mac.
2. Install python 2.6 - `sudo port install python26`
3. Install python 2.7 - `sudo port install python27`
4. You can use python26 through `/opt/local/bin/python2.6`
5. You can use python27 through `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`
6. If you want to use the python27 as default then do a `sudo port python-select python27`. This will ensure that `/opt/local/bin/python` is linked to `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`.

Mac comes with default python installation which is not removed. It can be accessed from `/usr/bin/python`.

Macports installs it's tools under path `/opt/local` and binaries at `/opt/local/bin`. So now you will have multiple versions of python and located at different location so that you can choose which one to run.

The packages installed with a particular version of python will go in it's site-packages and will not be available to other versions of python installation.

[Edit: based on comments]

I have multiple versions of standard python installation.

```
~ $ /usr/bin/python
python            python2.5         python2.6         pythonw           pythonw2.6        
python-config     python2.5-config  python2.6-config  pythonw2.5
```

With python2.5, I get:

```
>>> print platform.architecture()
('32bit', '')
>>> sys.maxint > 2**32
False
```

With python2.6, I get:

```
>>> print platform.architecture()
('64bit', '')
>>> sys.maxint > 2**32
True
```

See the note at - http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem I'm having is that I have two version of python2.7, one of which is 32-bit only, while the other is universal. Is their a way of specifying which of these two versions I want to build for. At the moment specifying python2.7 seems to default to the 32/64 bit version, whereas it's the other one that I need.

Comment: Also be aware that the port names for the various MacPorts python packages generally follow the naming scheme: `pynn-packagename`, where `nn` refers to the Python version, for example, `py27-distribute` (for 2.7) and `py32-distribute` (for 3.2).  For historical reasons, `py-packagename` ports (without a number) are normally the Python 2.4 version.

Comment: @Ned Deily: Thanks Ned! That clears up the naming convention of packages which is not easy to locate in macport documentation.

Comment: Do you mean instead of `sudo port install python27` I should try and use `sudo port install /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7` (which is my 32-bit only version).

Comment: @Ned Deily: I did finally realise this after mistakenly installing two or three versions for python 2.4. I'd assumed that the lack of a version number meant it was somehow 'universal', and worked with all pythons - a beginners mistake!

Comment: @Paul Patterson: No! sudo port install python27 will install at /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7     It looks like you have a default python27 installation already. why don't you look into /usr/bin/python27 or /usr/bin/python

Comment: Right. I'm struggling a bit now with what all these various versions of python are, but I've run a quick script with usr/bin/python as the executable. `sys.maxint` returns `2147483647`, while `platform.architecture()` returns `64-bit`. Does this help me/us? From what I know it denotes that the interpreter is operating in 32-bit mode, but when I run the same script with the path I put in my previous comment `.architecture` returns `32-bit` - I had assumed that these were the same version accessed via different roots.

Comment: The results of `platform.architecture()` are not reliable when used with OS X universal 64-/32-bit Pythons; trust `sys.maxint` or, on newer Pythons, `sys.maxsize`.